# Getting "AxiosError: connect ECONNREFUSED" when calling python api in nodejs

Tags: python, node.js, docker, api

I am trying to call an api in my python script in my node script but getting "AxiosError: connect ECONNREFUSED" error. I have checked that I am indeed running the flask app on localhost:5000 and the node app on localhost:5005 but not sure why the connection is being rejected. What am I doing wrong? Eventually I intend to containerize these microservices so if you have any advice on that it will be greatly appreciated.

config.js

```
export const FLASK_MICROSERVICE_URL= "http://localhost:5003/user";
```

app.js:

```
import express from "express";
import {FLASK_MICROSERVICE_URL} from './config.js'
import bodyParser from "body-parser";
import cors from "cors";
import axios from 'axios';
const app = express();
app.use(cors());
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.get("/user/:id", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const userId = req.params.id;
    const url = `${FLASK_MICROSERVICE_URL}/${userId}`;
    const response = await axios.get(url);
    res.send(response.data);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    res.sendStatus(500);
  }
});
```

python file:

```
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_cors import CORS

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = //db URI
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = False


db = SQLAlchemy(app)

CORS(app)

class User(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'user'


    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(64), nullable=False)
    email = db.Column(db.String(128), nullable=False)
    contact = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False)
    joined_date_time=db.Column(db.DateTime, nullable=False)
    birthdate=db.Column(db.DateTime,nullable=False)
    genre_preferred=db.Column(db.String(64),nullable=False)


    def __init__(self, user_id, username, email, contact, joined_date_time, birthdate, genre_preferred):
        self.user_id = user_id
        self.username = username
        self.email = email
        self.contact = contact
        self.joined_date_time=joined_date_time
        self.birthdate=birthdate
        self.genre_preferred=genre_preferred


    def json(self):
        return {"user_id": self.user_id, "username": self.username, "email": self.email, "contact": self.contact, "joined_date_time":self.joined_date_time, "birthdate":self.birthdate, "genre_preferred":self.genre_preferred}

@app.route("/user")
def get_all():
    users = User.query.all()
    if len(users):
        return jsonify(
            {
                "code": 200,
                "data": {
                    "users": [user.json() for user in users]
                }
            }
        )
    return jsonify(
        {
            "code": 404,
            "message": "There are no books."
        }
    ), 404



@app.route("/user/<string:user_id>")
def find_genre_by_user_id(user_id):
    user = User.query.filter_by(user_id=user_id).first()
    if user:
        genre_preferred=user.json()['genre_preferred']
        return genre_preferred
    return jsonify(
        {
            "code": 404,
            "message": "Preferred Genre not found."
        }
    ), 404



if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=5003, debug=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to use my private ip address instead of localhost in FLASK_MICROSERVICE_URL.